# What are channel transmittance, detection efficiency and coupling loss in CV-QKD in practical implementation?

Tags: quantum-state, qkd

I am new to CVQKD and I am struggling to understand the concept of channel transmission , detection efficiency and coupling losses. According to my understanding:
Channel Transmittance is realted to the power that is launched into the fiber channel to make the state weaker, the rest is reflected by a beam splitter? Is it true?
Detection efficinecy is related to BOB photodiode.
Coupling losses might be the loss of power in quantum state when being launched into the fiber.
But it does not make much sense to me as how to relate it with security analysis.

Can anyone please help me clarify these concepts?